# Cannot read property 'name' of null in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

before using populate it was working but just after i added a reference model comment this problem started but other things worked right. I am was learning to create the comment section and this is what all code looks like

```
===============================index.js============================
    var express      = require('express')
, app            = express()
, bodyParser     = require("body-parser")
, mongoose       = require("mongoose")
, Campground     = require("./models/Campground")
, seedDB         = require("./seeds")

seedDB();

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp_camp_3", 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, 
    () => console.log("Database is started")
);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // this will set the file in view engine i.e views directory as ejs files so that we dont have to mention .ejs every time redering them


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("landing");
});

//INDEX ROUTE 
app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res){
    //get all campgrounds from db
    Campground.find({}, function(err, allCampgrounds){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error");
        } else{
            // we are using the campgrounds file and in which a variable campgrounds we take all values one by one from allCampgrounds data from database
            res.render("index", {campgrounds: allCampgrounds});
        }
    });
});

//CREATE ROUTE
app.post("/campgrounds", function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var desc = req.body.description;
    var newCampground = {name:name, image:image, description: desc};

    Campground.create(newCampground, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error")
        } else{ 
             // after creating and sumbmitting the form filled we have to redirect to see the output on the submission of form
             res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
    });
});


//NEW ROUTE
app.get('/campgrounds/new', function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
});


//SHOW ROUTE
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
    //find the campground with provided id
    Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){console.log("Error")}
        else{
            console.log(foundCampground);
            //render show template with that campground
            res.render("show", {campground: foundCampground});
        }
    });
});


app.listen(1000, function(){
    console.log("server started");
});


==========seeds.js=================

    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Campground = require("./models/Campground")
var Comment = require("./models/comment")
var data = [
    {
        name: "camp one",
        image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1309587/pexels-photo-1309587.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
        description:"this is our first camp "
    },
    {
        name: "camp two",
        image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2376989/pexels-photo-2376989.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
        description:"this is our another camp "
    },
    {
        name: "camp Three",
        image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3776821/pexels-photo-3776821.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500",
        description:"this is our another camp "
    }
];





========================show.ejs==================================

    <%- include ('./partials/header.ejs') %> 
<h1><%= campground.name %> </h1>
<p>
   <img src="<%= campground.image %> " alt="hill"> 
</p>
<p>
    <%= campground.description %> 
</p>

<% campground.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <p> <%= comment.author %> <%= comment.text %>  </p>
    <% }) %> 

<%- include ('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

=================================================./models/campground.js=========

```
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//schema setup
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

=============================./models/comment.js========================

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

I am trying to resolve it and the code is almost same as the tutorial still I am having this issue. This error occur after I tried to use references for comment and used .populate("").

Comment: can you provide the schema of models?

Comment: OK... Mentioned above